# Android Studio: Snapshot Dependencies Don't Update properly

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, sonatype

I'm working With Android Studio 8.9

I've got a build.gradle with the following dependency defined:

```
compile ('my.program.commons:my-program-commons:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT@jar')
```

This dependency is stored in a private Sonatype nexus repository.

When I make changes in the my.program.commons code, I upload to nexus.

The problem is that when I then try to compile against the new SNAPSHOT android studio will fail to pick up changes.

When run from the command line gradle will build succesfully - but Android Studio will not recognize the new files.

If i do a version tick - say from 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT Android Studio will understand the new version and download and everything works out fine.

I don't want to have to do a minor version tick on every single change.

Comment: Wait.. Android Studio 8.9? Time travel? :)

Comment: This question is 5 years old lol.

Comment: I know.. :). `Android Studio 8.9` back in 2014... You must be a time traveller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure the cache duration, by default gradle won't look for updates for 24 hours:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling_caching

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out yesterday.  That coupled with marking the dependency as "changing" solved this problem.

Comment: It looks to me like marking a dependency as "changing" just allows it to use a potentially different (shorter) caching time if you specify one.  Otherwise, it must just use the "normal" caching time, which you could also specify as a shorter-than-usual duration.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, use `changing = true` not work for me. But configure cache changing modules solve my problem. Sample code below, add in `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all {
    // Don't cache changing modules at all.
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: This goes in the `dependencies` section.

Answer (score 10):

You can also put a flag called **"changing"** that will trigger Gradle to always pull the latest, for example:

```
compile ('my.program.commons:my-program-commons:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT@jar') {
 changing = true;
}
```

Comment: I found that you had to couple both he cache duration, and the changing value were required to guarantee this worked correctly.  Even so I still have to run --refresh-dependencies occasionally.  Checkout my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: how to use  --refresh-dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the whole `<project_root>/.idea/libraries` directory, was the only solution that worked. AndroidStudio stores some cached dependencies configurations there. Removing the directory makes it refetch all of them one more time.

You can write some script/task that will automate this removal and run it as part of the Gradle `clean` task.