# Why doesn't mopub gradle dependencies update automatically?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

There are two ways to update dependency in gradle:

1. Manually set the dependency version (ex: `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'`)
2. Define dependency as "changing" and let gradle do the work automatically (ex: `compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1') { changing = true }`)

My question is, why doesn't mopub and similar advertising SDKs update automatically (aka use the `changing` feature)?

Comment: Probably because of caching. See this for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610382/android-studio-snapshot-dependencies-dont-update-properly

Comment: I doubt it because the caching only applies for 24 hours